# I have hosted my Nodejs Application on Amazon AWS. Now it shows 502 bad gateway after some time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

I started the server using Command prompt by the command "sudo node server.js"
Then I closed the command prompt.
Now after some time, the website automatically shows 502 bad gateway error.
I had also used the command "sudo node server.js &" but it still not works.

Can you help me find out what could be the possible problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `pm2` to start your script so that it persist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you app is not running, here is why.

When start the application in the command line, the application is handled by that bash instance. When you close that instance, so does the application.

The solution to this is to use a package like **[pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)** which will make sure that your application is always running.